# CarrierWave multiple images in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, activeadmin, carrierwave

I have multiple images uploader for a model use carrierwave.

```
[![show do
    attributes_table do
      row :icon do |res|
        image_tag res.icon.url(:icon)
      end
      row :desc_images do |res|
        res.desc_images.each_with_index do |image, index|
          image_tag image.thumb.url
        end
      end
    end
  end]
```

[image]
**icon** is work

but **image_tag** of **desc_images** not work as show in image.

How could this show like row of **icon**, and where can I find document about this problem?

[ActiveAdmin document is too simple to read](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Showing-an-uploaded-image-in-the-form)

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to be ok, can you try adding it to a list

```
row :desc_images do
   ul do
    res.desc_images.each do |img|
      li do 
        image_tag(image.thumb.url)
      end
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you , I finnally find out problem. `permit_params`  should  add `desc_images: []`, not `:desc_images`